# jsp:include pointing to controller method not working on controller return

Tags: java, jsp, menu, controller, include

I am using a JSP:include tag on every view to show my menu.  Yesterday i found out that you can actually include a controller method which is very neat because it allows me to do some processing before returning the menu.  What I am doing is i'm adding this to every page :

```
<jsp:include page="/menu/showMenu"/>
```

I used to do just this :

```
<%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
```

This change allows me to pass boolean values to the model when the menu is returned which i am using to either display or not display certain options depending on what the user has access to.  This works perfectly when first loading a page but the menu completely disappears when any sort of controller processing is done.  For example, i have a log page with a table showing log entries from the database.  The column headers contain search fields which are part of a form that, when submitted, calls a controller method to filter the log list and display the filtered data.  The return statement from that controller method is simply :

```
return "logs";
```

This works perfectly when using the original include that points to the actual JSP file instead of the controller method but with the new approach of including a controller method the menu vanishes when the filtering logic returns the page.  What i can always do is include the JSP file as i used to and place the service calls in the JSP directly to check whether the user has access to each function but i really prefer the idea of having a controller doing this stuff and passing boolean values to the JSP.

Any idea why i'm seeing this behavior?  I can provide code examples if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed a pattern where the menu shows when returning from a GET request but doesn't show when returning from a POST request if that helps any.  All the GET methods return a page with the menu showing.

Comment: I figured it out!  I had to add a POST method to my menu controller.  It does exactly the same thing as the GET method but it is necessary when included in a page that is returned from another controller's POST method.  Hopes this can help someone!

Comment: assuming this isn't a duplicate question, you can provide a self-answer since you figured out the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I had to add a POST method to my menu controller. It does exactly the same thing as the GET method but it is necessary when included in a page that is returned from another controller's POST method. Hopes this can help someone!